# Investor's optimization problem with risk aversion

Tags: investment, optimization, risk-aversion

Consider an investor with initial wealth $w$ and has to decide how to invest it. There is a riskless asset with rate of return $r$. The risky asset has return $x_i$ with probability $\pi_i$ for $i=1,2,3,...,n$. Denote by $\alpha$ the fraction of wealth that investor puts into the risky asset, so that $1- \alpha$ is the fraction that he puts in the riskless asset. 
Write down the investor's optimization problem.

This is a question from my homework test. I want to specifically confirm my answer of part a), 
I wrote $$max \sum_{i=1}^{n} \pi _{i}[U((1-\alpha )w(1+r)-\alpha w+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i]$$

This, we have to maximise w.r.t. $\alpha$
Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Here $x_i$ means the interest rate/rate of return, right?

Comment: No, I think it's the whole amount which you'll get with probability $$\pi $$.                    Or I'm confused should the optimisation roblem be :

Comment: $$U[\alpha w+\alpha w\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\pi _{i}+(1-\alpha )w(1+r)]$$

Comment: Did you get your exam back? 

It doesn't make sense to me for $x_i$ to be anything other than a rate of return, comparable with $r$. Why do you think it's a coupon amount?

Comment: It may be, I don't know.

Comment: Nope, not yet! Can you help out even if $x_i$ is a rate of return. I'm unable to get a clue even ? Thank you so much!

Comment: To make the question more readable, consider typing it in instead of posting dim photos of it.

Comment: Done, sorry @SanderHeinsalu. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify a utility function over wealth so I'm using $u(\cdot)$. Assuming that $x_i$ is indeed a rate of return, the investor's optimization problem would be

$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\argmax_{\alpha \in \ [0,1]} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \pi_iu(w(1-\alpha)r + w\alpha x_i);
$$

that is, the investor wishes to find the optimal $\alpha \in [0,1]$ that maximizes expected utility over returns.

In words: with probability $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \pi_i = 1$ the investor earns the return $w(1-\alpha)r$ from the riskless asset, but with probability $\pi_i$ the investor earns the return $w\alpha x_i$ from the risky asset.

Comment: We've to do this by assuming $U(.)$ only. Can you help out in part b also?

Comment: If you are still interested in a response to part b, I suggest you open a new question that is clearly written in MathJax (no images please) and show all the work you were able to do and where you got stuck. I may be able to get to it -- no promises though. But someone else could give it a look as well.

Comment: Hey, I've a confusion, should we add $w$ in the utility function, since that's the principal amount and it should be added in the utility function. The utility function you've written does only include the interest amount.

Comment: No, because the investor wants to maximize **returns** by optimally distributing wealth over the assets. It doesn't matter what the initial wealth is, just the ratio between investments.